# selecting row if value of attribute in array of objects one of multiple values

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have data shaped like this: arrays of objects in a jsonb column in postgres

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"a":3, "b":"green"} ,{"a":5, "b":"blue"}] |
| 2 | [{"a":3, "b":"red"} ,{"a":5, "b":"yellow"}] |
| 3 | [{"a":3, "b":"orange"} ,{"a":5, "b":"blue"}] |

I am trying to select the rows where `b` is either `"green"` or `"yellow"`

I know I can unroll the data using `jsonb_array_elements` to get all the `b` values

```
select jsonb_array_elements(data) ->> 'b' from table
```

but I am failing to use that in a where query like this

```sql
 select * from table where jsonb_array_elements(data) ->> 'b' && ARRAY["green","yellow"]::varchar[]
```

(not working "set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE")

Comment: String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL. So it should be `array['gree', 'yellow']`. Boolean expressions are combined with `AND` not with `&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use subquery with a column alias name  and `ANY` like below

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  select *,jsonb_array_elements(data) ->> 'b' val 
  from t
) t1
WHERE t1.val = ANY (ARRAY['green','yellow'])
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=61d1ba16b802401df9382a826d135fbd)

**NOTE**

`ARRAY` filter value need to use single quote instead of double quote

Comment: works perfectly for my use-case, thank you

Comment: No problem glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@>` operator

```
select *
from the_table
where data @> '[{"b": "green"}]'
   or data @> '[{"b": "yellow"}]'
```

Or a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from the_table
where data @@ '$[*].b == "green" || $[*].b == "yellow"';
```

Or by unnesting the array with an EXISTS condition:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.data) as x(item)
              where x.item ->> 'b' in ('green', 'yellow'))
```